# Logging InputStream during consumption

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an object (specifically an instance of `HttpServletRequest` or `ServletRequest` which has a `#getInputStream` method that returns an instance of `ServletInputStream`. I want to log the content of the input stream, and I have tried to do so by wrapping the ServletRequest inside of a `ServletRequestWrapper` so that I could make the InputStream consumable multiple times. However, it does not seem to work. Is it possible to log the content of an inputstream while it is being consumed, so that it only needs to be consumed once?

Comment: Let's forget about the logging part (for the moment). Does your code invoke any of the `read` methods on the `ServletInputStream` object?

Comment: I am not myself invoking the read method explicitly. I am, however, passing the inputstream into a Filter chain, which must somehow (directly or indirectly) invoke this method.

Comment: I suggest, if possible, to log the contents of `ServletInputStream` in the part of your code where you read the contents.

Comment: But I want to be able to log the payload before actually processing it via any libraries

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something like a `LoggingInputStream`, that takes the original `InputStream` as constructor argument. And your implementation of the `read()` methods would log, what they read. And you would pass your `LoggingInputStream` to whoever wants to consume it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `ServletRequestWrapper` in `getInputStream()` method, return wrapped `ServletStream` inside `LoggingInputStream`. Something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //this object is just for demo purpose.
        ServletRequestWrapper srw = new ServletRequestWrapper();

        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(srw.getInputStream());
        int d =0;
        while((d= ir.read()) != -1) {
            //...
        }
    }
}

//extend ServletInputStream
class LoggingInputStream extends InputStream {
    private InputStream in;
    public LoggingInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int data = in.read();
        System.out.print((char)data + " ");
        return data;
    }
    //also override `readLine(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method for logging
}

class ServletRequestWrapper {
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        String data = "Data Start. Intercept this stream!";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
        
        //wrap original ServletInputStream in LoggingInputStream
        LoggingInputStream lis = new LoggingInputStream(is);
        
        return lis;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D a t a   S t a r t .   I n t e r c e p t   t h i s   s t r e a m ! ? ?
```